# combinatorics -- changing of the probability if $n$ is changing

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> If I have got $7$ white and $4$ black balls in a box and I take out $5$, what is the probability if at least $3$ of them are black?  How does this probability changes if we double the number of balls in the box (add $7$ more white and $4$ more black)?

My answer:

I tried to calculate the probability of the first case. There are $6$ options:

\begin{align*}
  0~\text{white}| 5~\text{black} & = 0\\
  1~\text{white}|4~\text{black}  & =  { 7  \choose 1}{ 4  \choose 4} =  \frac{7!}{1!6!} \cdot \frac{4!}{4!0!} = 7 \cdot 1 = 7\\
  2~\text{white}|3~\text{black} & = { 7  \choose 2}{ 4  \choose 3} =  \frac{7!}{2!5!} \cdot \frac{4!}{3!1!} = 21 \cdot 4 = 84\\
  3~\text{white}|2~\text{black} & = { 7  \choose 3}{ 4  \choose 2} =  \frac{7!}{3!4!} \cdot \frac{4!}{2!2!} = 35 \cdot 6 = 210 \\
  4~\text{white}|1~\text{black} & = { 7  \choose 4}{ 4  \choose 1} =  \frac{7!}{4!3!} \cdot \frac{4!}{1!3!} = 35 \cdot 4 = 140\\
  5~\text{white}|0~\text{black} & = { 7  \choose 5}{ 4  \choose 0} =  \frac{7!}{5!2!} \cdot \frac{4!}{0!4!} = 21 
\end{align*}

From there the top $3$ is the case where we have got at least $3$ black.  Which is: $91$.  That number of all possible combinations is the sum of all, which is: $462$.  So the probability of at least three black is: $91/462$.

My first question: Am I right with this calculation?

2, I calculated the same way the probability with $14$ white and $8$ black.

\begin{align*}
  0~\text{white}| 5~\text{black} & = 56 \\
  1~\text{white}|4~\text{black} & = 14 \cdot 70 = 980  \\
  2~\text{white}|3~\text{black} & = 91 \cdot 28 = 2548 \\
  3~\text{white}|2~\text{black} & =  364 \cdot 70 = 25480 \\
  4~\text{white}|1~\text{black} & = 1001 \cdot 8 = 8008 \\
  5~\text{white}|0~\text{black} & =   2002 \\
\end{align*}

So the probability in this case is $3584/39074$.

My second question: Is there any better way to calculate this if we know the first case result?  At the moment these are two independent calculations.

Regards,

-------------------Update------------------

As it was pointed out I miscalculated the 2nd case.  The right answer:

\begin{align*}
  0~\text{white}| 5~\text{black} & = 56 \\
  1~\text{white}|4~\text{black} & = 14 \cdot 70 = 980  \\
  2~\text{white}|3~\text{black} & = 91 \cdot 56 = 5096 \\
  3~\text{white}|2~\text{black} & =  364 \cdot 28 = 10192 \\
  4~\text{white}|1~\text{black} & = 1001 \cdot 8 = 8008 \\
  5~\text{white}|0~\text{black} & =   2002 \\
\end{align*}

Probability is: 6132/26334

Comment: Q1: It looks right too me. Q2: I don´t see a way to simplify the calculation for the second question based on the result of the first question.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to the first question is correct.   To see this, observe that the denominator is the number of ways we can select $5$ of the $7 + 4 = 11$ balls, which is 
$$\binom{11}{5}$$
Since there are only four black balls, the number of favorable cases is the number of ways we can select three of the four black balls and two of the seven white balls or all four black balls and one of the seven white balls, which is 
$$\binom{4}{3}\binom{7}{2} + \binom{4}{4}\binom{7}{1}$$
Hence, the probability is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{4}{3}\dbinom{7}{2} + \dbinom{4}{4}\dbinom{7}{1}}{\dbinom{11}{5}}$$

Your answer to the second question is incorrect since you calculated the cases with three black and two white balls and two black and three white balls incorrectly.  Note that $\binom{8}{3} = 56$ rather than $28$ and that $\binom{8}{2} = 28$ rather than $70$.

This time we are selecting $5$ of the $14 + 8 = 22$ balls, so the denominator is

> $$\binom{22}{5}$$

Since we now have eight black balls, the number of favorable cases is the number of ways we can select three of the eight black balls and two of the fourteen white balls or four of the eight black balls and one of the eight white balls or five of the eight black balls and none of the fourteen white balls.

> $$\binom{8}{3}\binom{14}{2} + \binom{8}{4}\binom{14}{1} + \binom{8}{5}\binom{14}{0}$$

Therefore, the desired probability is

> $$\frac{\dbinom{8}{3}\dbinom{14}{2} + \dbinom{8}{4}\dbinom{14}{1} + \dbinom{8}{5}\dbinom{14}{0}}{\dbinom{22}{5}}$$

Comment: So the right number are: 56,980,5096,10192,8008,2002 = 6132/26334 

It is interesting. So the probability is increasing when we increase the n.  Somehow I was thinking the opposite.

Comment: New question: what is the limit of this increase?

Comment: Observe that the largest number is $10192$, which occurs when we select $3$ of the $14$ white balls and $2$ of the $8$ black balls.

Comment: Notice that $\binom{14}{j}$ is largest when $j = 14/2 = 7$ and that $\binom{8}{k}$ is largest when $k = 8/2 = 4$.  However, we have the additional constraint that $j + k = 5$.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right with the method that you've used.

Simpler way of doing this would be exclusion principle i.e.,

$ \frac{Total \ no. \ of\ ways\ of selecting \ 5 \ balls - Total \ no. \ of\ ways\ of selecting \ either\ 0 \ or\ 1\ or\ 2\ black\ balls}{Total \ no. \ of\ ways\ of selecting \ 5 \ balls}$

So, $ P=\frac{^{11}C_5 -(^7C_5*^4C_0+^7C_4*^4C_1+^7C_3*^4C_2)}{{^{11}C_5}}$

Similarly, in the second case as well.

Comment: It is worth noting that the OP's second answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Taussing You're right. Indeed, I didn't go through his calculations earlier and just checked the logic he had used (which would quickly grow long and cumbersome in cases where there are more number of balls present and the no. of balls to be picked is less). So, I just decided to post a more efficient solution.